# setAutoCommit is False yet program still runs SQL Statement as if Autocommit = True?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm writing a java program to work with a mySQL database, I've set the autocommit to false so that I can choose which statement i want to execute, yet the program doesn't allow me to enter any statement and autocommits all the statements, any advice?

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
              ("jdbc:mysql://"+host+":3306/com345db", user, pass);
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

// Creating a statement lets us issue commands against the connection.
Statement s = conn.createStatement();   
 // Creating and populating Actor table

 s.executeUpdate("create table IF NOT EXISTS Actor( ActorName VARCHAR(20)  
PRIMARY KEY,  Sex VARCHAR(6), Nationality VARCHAR(20), DOB DATE,  
DebutFilmTitle VARCHAR(30))");

 System.out.println("Created table Actor");

 s.executeUpdate("insert into Actor values('George Clooney', 'Male', 
'American', Date'1965-12-04','Casualty')");

 conn.commit();

 System.out.println("Inserted some actors");   
 ResultSet result=s.executeQuery("Select * From Actor");
 System.out.println("Results: ");
 while(result.next()) {
 System.out.println(result.getString(1) +"  "+ result.getString(2) + "  
"+result.getString(3) +"  "+  result.getString(4)+"  "+ result.getString(5) 
);
 }
 // We end the transaction and the connection.

 conn.commit();


 conn.close();
}
```

Comment: You do have a conn.commit(); in the middle. I don't see what is your problem

Comment: What is your code supposed to demonstrate? You manually commit your insertion!

Comment: my problem is that the program is meant to wait for me to type in s to execute the sql statement, but the program runs the sql statement without me typing anything into console

Comment: Hint:  System.in.read()

Comment: You are never waiting for input.